# Show that the third derivative of a unit space curve equals $-k^2 \mathbf{t} + k'\mathbf{n} + \mathcal{t}k\mathbf{b}$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Show that the third derivative of a unit space curve equals $-k^2 \mathbf{t} + k'\mathbf{n} + \mathcal{T}k\mathbf{b}$ where $k$ is its curvature and $\mathcal{T}$ is its torsion.

I'm not clear on what the exercise means by $\mathbf{t}, \mathbf{n}, \mathbf{b}$. Does anyone have advice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses fairly standard terminology for 3-dimensional vectors.

$\mathbf{r}$ is a differentiable vector function of time. In this problem it is a unit space curve, so you know that

$$|\mathbf{r}|=1 \quad\text{for all $t$}$$

$\mathbf{t}$ is the unit tangent vector to the curve, which can be defined by

$$\mathbf{t}=\frac{d\mathbf{r}/dt}{|d\mathbf{r}/dt|}$$

$\mathbf{n}$ is the principal unit normal to the curve, which can be defined by

$$\mathbf{n}=\frac{d\mathbf{t}/dt}{|d\mathbf{t}/dt|}$$

$\mathbf{b}$ is the binormal vector of the curve, which is a unit vector orthogonal to both $\mathbf{t}$ and $\mathbf{n}$, which can be defined by

$$\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{t} \times \mathbf{n}$$

There are other definitions, most of them using the arc length, curvature, and torsion functions of the curve. Ask if you need those definitions or more on your problem.

Comment: Oh, I have been seeing those definitions as capital letters. That is what I was confused though now I'm a bit stuck on the actual exercise haha.